# How to download files through IMCE file browser?

Tags: 7, files

I found the IMCE has upload and delete buttons, but not download. Is there a way to add download feature, if so how?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one built into the module. One work around is to use IMCE user file browser (**/user/[uid]/imce**) and click on the preview image. It will open up the image URL in a new tab/window where you can download it through your browser.